# Dijkstra's algorithm - adjacency matrix and list

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

I've got strange problem with my Dijkstra's implementation... I have 2 algorithms, one for adjacency matrix and the second one for adjacency list. They are almost identical and only difference is with passing numbers from these structures.

I keep numbers from matrix in simple two-dimensional matrix called weightmat.
Numbers from list are kept in array of lists called nbhlist.
Lists are composed from structs called ListNode.

```
struct ListNode{    
        int number;             
        int weight;         
        ListNode* next;             
        ListNode(){                         
            number = weight = 0;
            next = 0;
        }
    };
```

And few general variables: vertex (number of vertices), edge (number of edges), vstart (number of start vertex).

Now code of Dijkstra's algorithm for matrix:

```
typedef vector<vector<pair<int, float> > > Graph;
struct Compare{
    int operator() (const pair<int,float>& p1, const pair<int,float>& p2)
    {
        return p1.second > p2.second;
    }
};

vector<float> d(vertex);
vector<int> parent(vertex);

for (int i = 0; i < vertex; i++){
    d[i] = numeric_limits<float>::max();
    parent[i] = -1;
}

priority_queue<pair<int, float>, vector<pair<int, float> >, Compare> MatQueue;

d[vstart] = 0;
MatQueue.push(make_pair(vstart, d[vstart]));
while (!MatQueue.empty()){
    int u = MatQueue.top().first;
    if (u == vertex - 1) break;
    MatQueue.pop();
    for (int i = 0; i < vertex; i++){
        if (weightmat[u][i] != 0){
            int v = i;
            float w = weightmat[u][i];
            //cout << "U " << u << "Number " << i << " Weight " << weightmat[u][i] << endl;
            if (d[v]> d[u] + w){
                d[v] = d[u] + w;
                parent[v] = u;
                MatQueue.push(make_pair(v, d[v]));
            }
        }
    }
}

vector<int> path;
path.clear();
int p = vertex - 1;
path.push_back(vertex - 1);
while (p != vstart)
{
    p = parent[p];
    path.push_back(p);
}
for (int i = path.size()-1; i >=0; i--){
    cout << path[i] << "->";
}
```

And this is code of Dijkstra's algorithm for my lists:

```
typedef vector<vector<pair<int, float> > > Graph;

    struct Compare{
        int operator() (const pair<int, float>& p1, const pair<int, float>& p2)
        {
            return p1.second > p2.second;
        }
    };

    vector<float> d(vertex);
    vector<int> parent(vertex);

    for (int i = 0; i < vertex; i++){
        d[i] = numeric_limits<float>::max();
        parent[i] = -1;
    }

    priority_queue<pair<int, float>, vector<pair<int, float> >, Compare> MatQueue;

    d[vstart] = 0;
    MatQueue.push(make_pair(vstart, d[vstart]));

    ListNode* hand = new ListNode;

    while (!MatQueue.empty()){
        int u = MatQueue.top().first;
        if (u == vertex - 1) break;
        MatQueue.pop();
        hand = NbhList[u];
        while (hand){
            int v = hand->number;
            float w = hand->weight;
            //cout << "U " << u << "Number " << v << " Weight " << w << endl;
            hand = hand->next;
            if (d[v] > d[u] + w){
                d[v] = d[u] + w;
                parent[v] = u;
                MatQueue.push(make_pair(v, d[v]));
            }
        }
    }


    vector<int> path;
    path.clear();
    int p = (vertex-1);
    path.push_back(p);
    while (p != vstart)
    {
        p = parent[p];
        path.push_back(p);
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    for (int i = path.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        cout << path[i] << "->";
    }
```

As I said, they are almost identical. Only difference:

```
MatQueue.pop();
        hand = NbhList[u];
        while (hand){
            int v = hand->number;
            float w = hand->weight;
            //cout << "U " << u << "Number " << v << " Weight " << w << endl;
            hand = hand->next;
            if (d[v] > d[u] + w){
                d[v] = d[u] + w;
                parent[v] = u;
                MatQueue.push(make_pair(v, d[v]));
            }
        }
```

And:

```
MatQueue.pop();
        for (int i = 0; i < vertex; i++){
            if (weightmat[u][i] != 0){
                int v = i;
                float w = weightmat[u][i];
                //cout << "U " << u << "Number " << i << " Weight " << weightmat[u][i] << endl;
                if (d[v]> d[u] + w){
                    d[v] = d[u] + w;
                    parent[v] = u;
                    MatQueue.push(make_pair(v, d[v]));
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem is - they give me sometimes different outputs and I have no idea why.
Could you help me find my problem?

Comment: I suspect that the problem lies in how you're building your lists of neighbours.

Comment: If your algorithms are nearly identical, and the only difference is the representation of your graph (matrix vs adj list) perhaps it would help you to use an interface for your graph representations, and then use only one version of the algorithm. That way, you can make tests to guarantee that the representations act the same way for getting/setting vertices and edges, etc.

Comment: So which one gives the correct answer, if any?

Comment: About 20:30 I'll be back at home and I'll check solution.

Comment: @gilleain but this is my task - to study on how different representations act (how fast) on this algorithm

Answer (score 2):

One possible bug is that in your `ListNode` struct:

```
struct ListNode{    
        int number;             
        int weight;         
        ListNode* next;             
        ListNode(){                         
            number = weight = 0;
            next = 0;
        }
    };
```

`weight` is an `int`, but your weights are `float`s according to the rest of your code, which might result in unwanted truncation.

Comment: Nope, that was not a problem. Currently I'm trying to find which of structures give me wrong output. Differences appears only with more than 10 vertices and about 100% density of graph, so that's difficult to find.

Comment: Okay, now I'm pretty much sure that I have problem with matrix.

Comment: @EDIT NO! Now I really don't know what to do... Sometimes matrix algorithm gives me right path, sometimes list algorithm

Comment: @DzikiChrzan can you please post an input, the two different outputs of your algorithms, and the correct answer?